# VBA to loop though named range, filter at table and copy results to other sheet

Tags: loops, filter, copy, paste

I have an issue with filtering a table based on values in a named range (can be 3 values or as many as 50). I create this range with another macro.

The filtered table is then needs to be copied and pasted into another tab. The results of the second filter should then be copied to the same tab as the first (just a few rows space).

I have found lots of topics on this but none that I can really understand. I am happy to provide more details.

Comment: Can you post example code you might have tried and details on the issue you were having?

Comment: Hi khalid,I dont have any code already as I am not sure where to start with it.